# maven interface and implementation best practices

Tags: maven, interface, pom.xml, implementation

I have one JAR that contains multiple classes. I have two packages inside such JAR: one containing interfaces and one implementations. I've been reading that it is not a good idea to have JARs inside JARs http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/#.Ve83FPF7Gtg . I was wondering if it is a good idea to use the JAR plugin to separate and include two JARs (impl and interface) inside my parent JAR or change the parent POM to include the other two as dependencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I usually create two seperate modules, impl and api. For example: "server-api" contains all server side interfaces while "server" contains the implementation.

In addition, my parent pom define them both under "dependencyManagement" while server also depends on server-api using the version from the parent.

As written in the post you mentioned, it's a good practice to have multiple jars generated from a single module.